# Android service timer

Tags: android, audio, service, timer

Can an audio service be set to a timer? Example would be for a sleep machine type app where the user clicks the time they want the sound to play and then the sound plays for that time. I was told that using a service to handle the audio was the proper way but I do not know how to get it to work with a timer for a user selected input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, yes it is possible.
I have done audio recording using a background service, have also done FTP downloads in a background service.
You would use a started service in this case, it will play audio using following:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

You may pass a value from Activity to Service using intent extras, for example

```
Intent intService =  new Intent(AndroidSignageActivity.this, SignageDownloadService.class);
intService.putExtra("TIMEVAL_MILLISEC", 1000);//
startService(intService);
```

In the service, you can extract the value and use it in onStartCommand method as following:

```
long lTimeout = 0;
if(intent.hasExtra("TIMEVAL_MILLISEC")){
 lTimeout = intent.getLongExtra("TIMEVAL_MILLISEC", 100);
}
```

Comment: I have my service playing the audio when the start button is clicked but it will only play until the audio clips runs out or if I set looping to true then it does not stop until the stop button is pressed. I have a spinner with times on my layout but I dont know how to move the selected time to the service to play for that length

Comment: We start the service using an intent, you can send the time value to the service through the intent extras.

Comment: so the extra intent goes in the activity referencing the spinner while the second block of code you posted gets the time selected by the spinner in the  activity and passes that time to the service?

Comment: I put in your code and when I run it the timeout stays 0, it isnt pulling what was selected by the spinner